# Finding Joint Probability Using Marginal Density Functions?

Tags: probability

> I was asked to represent $\Pr(X>x, Y>y)$ using the marginal distribution functions. The question didn't mention anything about independence. How would one do this?

Comment: Your instinct "we can't without independence" (or more information, anyhow) seems correct to me.

Comment: You can't (uniquely) determine the joint probability just with marginal distributions and no other information (like independence, that's right).

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to find examples of different joint distributions with the same marginal distributions.

Just take any continuous joint distribution with a density that has its support in a rectangular domain (or an unbounded equivalent of a rectangle), say $$f_{XY}(x,y)=k\,(x+y)\,\chi_{[0,1]}(x)\, \chi_{[0,1]}(y),$$ where $\chi_A$ is the characteristic function of set $A$ and $k\in (0,+\infty)$ is a such that the $f_{XY}$ integrates up to $1$ (that is, such that it actually be a density).

Then you can find a marginal density function for $X$ and for $Y$ as
$$f_X(x)=\int_{\mathbb R} f_{XY}(x,y) dy$$
and
$$f_Y(y)=\int_{\mathbb R} f_{XY}(x,y) dx.$$

Now if you define $g(x,y)=f_X(x)f_Y(y)$ this is also a joint density function, but not for the same distribution since any two variables with that distribution are independent (or just because $g$ and $f_{XY}$ are essentially different functions—as you'll see if do the calculations.)